# Can you decrypt multiple concatenated RSA packets?

Tags: performance, encryption, rsa

I have many short messages, each encoded with RSA and the same key. I want to decrypt all of these in a performant way.

As a test, I created some 32-char random plaintexts, and encrypted them with a dummy RSA key. I then tried to decrypt them individually using `openssl rsautl -decrypt` and GNU Parallel. This took about 30 ms per message.

However, I'm now thinking that I can reduce overhead by simply concatenating all the messages and decrypting them as one big blob. However, I don't know if RSA works that way, since it would have to know that there are multiple messages and not just one.

Is this a logical way of increasing RSA decryption throughput? Or is decrypting them one by one as good as it gets?

Answer (score 0):

One way to increase your throughput is to use an efficient symmetric encryption algorithm such as AES. You first generate a AES key then encrypt it with RSA and transmit it. The data itself is then encrypted with AES and sent. The receiving end decrypts the AES key using RSA and then decrypts the data using AES. Being a block cypher, RSA can only encrypt one block of a fixed size at a time. So no performance gain to be gleaned by modifying input size to RSA.

Another option is to use multiple threads to encrypt several blocks at a time. It will go proportionally as fast as you have cores in the CPU.

Comment: In this case, I do not have control over the encryption scheme. It has to be RSA.